# Transforming Observable with .map

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a problem with transforming my observable. Details below:

I have a data like this

```js
[
    {
      'firstName': 'John',
      'lastName': 'Cash',
      'age': 20
    }
  ];
```

Then I get this data from api:

```js
  public getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.http.get('xxx')
    .map(
      response => response.json()
    );
  }
```

Then, I'm trying to subscribe this:

```js
this.service.getData.subscribe(
        (res) => this.data = res
      );
```

And It's ok, it's working. But I need to modify the structure of object and I would like to use .map to transform received object to this schema:

```js
[
    {
      'firstName': 'John',
      'lastName': 'Cash',
      'age': 20,
'newProperty': 'value'
    }
  ];
```

.. and nothing working for me.. :/ Even if I don't want to add new property, but modify a value on for example firstName:

```js
  .map(
    return x => x[0].firstName = 'asd'
  )
```

it's not working (Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Data[]', I know what it means, but I don't know how to do that, where is my mistake?)

Comment: i thin before retuning you need to create object of that type

Comment: But without creating new Object? For example by creating completely new array of objects with that data (without type) with new property? Maybe with spread function. Maybe it's have not any sense..

Or maybe I don't need to modify structure, maybe there is a possibility to  add variable to .map and copy there different value for each element of observable?

Comment: for example the new variable will be fullName with data from firstName and LastName.

Answer (score 18):

There's a difference between *map* operator in Observable and *map* method of array. You want to transform the result of HTTP request to array and then apply some additional transformation to every member of that array. Let's go step by step.

```js
this.http.get('...')
```

This returns the Observable object, which holds the Response of angular's Http service. To make use of the data inside of it, you have to call Response's *json()* method.

```js
.pipe(
  map((response:Response) => response.json())
)
```

This code means 'when the observable sends some data, put it into a processing pipe. Treat it as HTTP response and extract its content as JSON, then put to another Observable'. So if you subscribe to it, you'll get your array.

Then you can do anything with that regular array, like using its *map* method. Let me use my own example though it's very similar to yours.

```js
this.http.get('...')
.pipe(map((response:Response) => response.json()))
.subscribe((array:Person[]) => {
     let modifiedArray = array.map((item:any) => {
           item.newProperty = 'value';
     }

     this.persons = modifiedArray;
});
```

Or, if you like to, manipulate array items before subscription:

```js
const modifiedData$:Observable<Person> = this.http.get('...').pipe(
  map((response:Response) => response.json()),
  map((array:Person[]) => {
     return array.map((item:Person) => {
           item.newProperty = 'value';
     }
)};
```

Two consecutive *map* operators in pipe can be replaced with a single one:

```js
const modifiedData$:Observable<Person[]> = this.http.get('...')
  .pipe(map((response:Response) => {
     return response.json().map((item:Person) => {
       item.newProperty = 'value';
     }
  });

modifiedData$.subscribe((persons:Person[]) => {
     this.persons = modifiedArray;
});
```

If it's too wordy to you, here's a more compact (but less readable) version:

```js
this.http.get('...')
.pipe(map(response => response.json().map(item => item.newProperty = 'value')))
.subscribe(persons => this.persons = persons);
```

Comment: Makes sense except the map function doesn't exist on Observable. Not sure what version of rxjs I have.

Comment: Starting with version 5.5 of rxjs operators like `map` became pure functions and should be used inside a pipe. Edited my answer.

Comment: Ah yes doing it with pipe worked for me too. I forgot to put something in here about that working.

Comment: @Anton Rusak, do you mind looking at my post. I have something similar. I tried the above solution but its not applying well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205181/how-to-i-extract-values-that-are-returned-from-a-post-method-of-a-controller-fro?noredirect=1#comment110016046_62205181

Answer (score 4):

you have to create object of that type , for example as below

```js
.map((res: Response) => res.json().map(obj => new MyObject(obj.id, obj.name)))
```