# How transform values (true or false to Yes or No) in Array with objects with RXJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I receive the following (example) data from Firebase:

```
[
  {
    'customer': 'John',
    'active': true
  },
  {
    'customer': 'Doe',
    'active': true
  },
  {
    'customer': 'Frenz',
    'active': false
  }
];
```

In my table I want to show the value as 'Yes' or 'No'.
I'm using Angular so I want to change the values when I subscribe to te observerable.

So far I think I have to use the map-operator like: [Transforming Observable with .map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197223/transforming-observable-with-map)

But this example adds a value, I want to change every value in every object.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` (I'm assuming you're using RxJS 5.5):

```
source
  .pipe(
    map(array => array.map(obj => {
      obj.active = obj.active ? 'Yes' : 'No';
      return obj;
    })),
  )
```

I know it looks weird to use two `map`s but the outer one is from RxJS and the inner one is just `Array.map` that updates each object.

Comment: Also make sure to import the RxJS pipeable map operator like this: import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';