# Transform the array of objects returned as Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs6

There is small correction.
What we are returning is Object[] and not Object. 
The method signature is also changed as below - 
I have a method which returns `Observable` as below-

```
 getData(url: string): Observable<Object[]> {

    return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
  }
```

Where the `Object` is like below :

```
{

  property1 : value1 
  property2 : value2 
  property3 : "" // no value right now 
}
```

What I want to do is :

return `Observable<Object[]>` (**Please note same object**)

Where the Object is like below :

```
{

  property1 : value1 
  property2 : value2 
  property3 : value1 + value2; //combine property1 and property2 values 
}
```

How can we achieve this ?

I know we have to use `rxjs map operator` but how do we use it ?

The url [Transforming Observable with .map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197223/transforming-observable-with-map) talks about transforming Array but not Map

How can we achieve this using `Map operator` on `Observable` ?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-del)?

Comment: `.map(obj => ({...obj, property3: obj[property1] + obj[property2]})`

Comment: Your method signature is not TypeScript, looks more like C# or Java, so this can't be valid Angular code. What problem do you have with returning the object as you described?

Comment: The question is edited . Can you take a look please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you need to map data of `Observable` before it's been subscribed.

There's a function called `pipe` that used to modify data of `Observable` and returns an `Observable`.

For your case:

```
Observable<Object> getData(){
    // let assume your observable is called getObs
    return getObs.pipe(
        map(objs => objs.map(obj => {
            obj[property3] = obj[property1] + obj[property2]);
            return objs;
        })
        )
    )
}
```

Btw, all `rxjs/operators` must be called inside `pipe` function, not just `map`.

Comment: Okay, check it now