# Call a function from a other Object

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, object, instance

I get data from a MongoDB. This data is collected in a array by the ngOnInit() method. All the data is collected how i said in a array which type is a object. This object is outside of the app.component.ts file. I this object class there is class, lets call it getName():string{} which is returning a string with all the Names from the Object. When i want to interact with this function from the app.component.ts like so:

this.exampleObject[0].getName();

I am getting the following error on the side:
ERROR TypeError: this.exampleObject[0].getName is not a function

I realy do not understand that. Its an object oriented language how can it not call that function. The function is in the global scope and when i type this.exampleObject. there is also shown that function and when i rename that function in the other class it shows a error before compiling.

I realy hope, that someone can help me.

PS: And dont worry, exampleObject[0] != null. There is a correct object in.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    public persons: Person[] = [];
    constructor(private personService: PersonService){}
    ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getPersons();
    }
    public getPersons(): void{
            this.personService.findAll().subscribe(
            (response: Person[]) => {
                this.persons = response;
                //This should work:
                this.persons[0].getName(); //-> ERROR
                console.log(response);
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                alert(error.message);
            }
            );
        }
    }
}

export class Person{
    constructor(){}
    personName: String="";
    public getName(){
        return "HALLO WORLD";
    }
}

export class PersonService{
  /**
   * This is the current URL from the backend
   */
  private personUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/person';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public findAll(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.http.get<Person[]>(this.personUrl);
  }
}
```

1. I tried diffrent diffentions of functions. Nothing worked
2. I tested the length of the array, if there is data. And ye there is.
3. I can access the variables from that object and get output
4. I can access the function name (it shows up how i said) but when i compile there is that error

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I don't work with Angular. But I'm fairly sure I know what's wrong, and *probably* how to fix it.

In your service code, you're using a type assertion to say that what you get from `this.http.get` is an array of `Person` instances, but unless you have something injected somewhere you haven't shown, it can't be. I suspect it's either:

1. A `Response` object, if you don't have something injected that processes the response.

   or (if something has already done that)
2. An array of plain objects — **not** `Person` instances — each with a `personName` property.

Even if #1 isn't necessary in your setup, #2 probably is. So what you really have as of reading the JSON is an array of `{personName: string;}`, not an array of `Person`. Let's give ourselvse a `PersonLike` type that describes that (basically, `Person` without methods):

```typescript
type PersonLike = {
    [Key in keyof Person as Person[Key] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? never : Key]: Person[Key];
};
```

You need to pipe your observable through steps that will

1. Read and parse the JSON (if that's not already happening)
2. Convert the plain objects into `Person` instances

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46215263/157247), I think that will look like this:

```typescript
public findAll(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.personUrl).pipe(
        // Read and parse the JSON from the response
        map((response: Response) => response.json()),
        // Convert the data-only `PersonLike` objects into actual `Person` instances
        map((array: PersonLike[]) =>
            array.map((dataPerson: Person) =>
                Object.assign(new Person(), dataPerson)
            )
        )
    )};
}
```

If you don't need the JSON part, just:

```typescript
public findAll(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.personUrl).pipe(
        // Convert the data-only `PersonLike` objects into actual `Person` instances
        map((array: PersonLike[]) =>
            array.map((dataPerson: Person) =>
                Object.assign(new Person(), dataPerson)
            )
        )
    )};
}
```

Comment: So the findAll().subscribe(...) method would stay as it is?

Comment: @BenediktMüller - That's my understanding, yes, because we're handling the instance creation in `findAll`.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that you have to map a new instance for that specific "Person". The raw data from response is just a instance with that fields from the MongoDB. So there is no function called "X". The way you can do that is:

```
   public getPersons(): void{
            this.personService.findAll().subscribe(
            (response: Person[]) => {
                this.persons = response.map((person)=>new Person);//You also can insert parameters: 
//new Person(person.X,person,Y) if you have not a 
//NoArgs constructor.
                //This should work:                console.log(response);
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                alert(error.message);
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: That won't set `personName` on the new `Person` instances. I'm in the process of writing up an answer that will.